# What sound change(s) underlie [iʒ-] in São Vicente?

Tags: sound-change, portuguese, creoles

Is there a particular sound change that would explain changing a word-initial [ʒu] (or alternatively [dʒu]) to [iʒ] before a stressed syllable? Or might this be best explained as dropping the [u] by syncope and adding a [i] by prothesis?

I found this in a couple words of [the São Vicente dialect of Cape Verdean Creole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Verdean_Creole#Barlavento), which is related to both Portuguese and other dialects of Cape Verdean Creole:

```
| Portuguese        | Sotavento Creoles | São Vicente |
|-------------------|-------------------|-------------|
| jogar   [ʒug'aɾ]  | ['dʒugɐ]          | [iʒ'ga]     |
| ajudar [ɐʒudˈaɾ]  | ['dʒudɐ]          | [iʒ'da]     |
```

This dialect often elides unstressed [i] and [u] sounds in words, compared to other dialects or languages. So a change from [ʒu-] → [ʒ-] (or [dʒu-] → [ʒu-] → [ʒ-]) would make some sense. In other languages I'm familiar with, [ʒda] or [ʒga] would be seen as "unpronounceable", so adding an initial vowel could make sense.

However, this particular dialect elided many (most?) of the initial unstressed vowels present in Portuguese. Many words start with [ʃt-], [ʃk-], [ʃp-], etc. The dialect seems very comfortable with consonant clusters at the start of words: commonly-used words include [tʃga], [pʰta], [fka], and [zbi]. There *are* other cases of vowel prothesis, however.

Is there another sound change I should be looking at for a possible explanation? Or is ([dʒu-] →) [ʒu-] → [ʒ-] → [iʒ-] the best bet?

---

<sub>(I started to wonder more about this when I heard a speaker of this dialect pronounce a name [iʃ'sɛ] instead of the standard [ʒu'zɛ]. This speaker has both speech and hearing disorders, so isn't representative of all speakers, but the sound change was so similar that I wondered if this is a pattern seen in other languages.)</sub>

---

A couple notes about other prothetic vowels from @KennyLau's questions:

Words that come from Portuguese words starting with "es" plus a consonant generally have no initial vowel (as is common in Portugal), across the dialects of Cape Verdean Creole.

```
| Portuguese | Sotavento Creoles | São Vicente |
|------------|-------------------|-------------|
| escola     | ['skɔlɐ]          | ['ʃkɔlɐ]    |
```

Another example of vowel prothesis in the São Vicente dialect is the addition of an initial /a/ in certain words:

```
| European Portuguese | Sotavento Creoles | São Vicente |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------|
| mulher [muʎˈɛɾ]     | [mu'dʒɛɾ]         | [am'dʒɛʀ]   |
| melhor [mɘʎˈɔɾ]     | [mi'dʒoɾ]         | [am'dʒoʀ]   |
```

However, this might not be consistent for all speakers of the São Vicente dialect, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Verdean_Creole#Barlavento) seems to say that these start with a syllabic m, instead of [am].

Comment: Semirelated: In Mirandese (the other official language of Portugal), some unstressed CV(C) syllables have become syllabic fricatives (the most obvious being *z-* and *ç-* for Romance *des-*).  These evolved from the elided vowels that, in modern Portuguese, are frequently pronounced voiceless.  Your progression of [ʒu-] → [ʒ-] → [iʒ-] seems, at least, incredibly plausible.  When you cite [tʃ'ga] / [p'ta], is the  [tʃ] and [p] fully syllabic?

Comment: @guifa to be honest the only one of those 4 examples that I'm certain is 2 syllables is [d'bɔʃ]. The others might not be. Is there an easy way to tell the difference?

Comment: that can sometimes be a bit harder to peg down.  In writing you certainly couldn't and in speech can be tricky because it happens on unstressed syllables, but in a song, it'd ought to be easier: if [tʃ] gets one note, and [ga] another, then it's probably syllabic.  If they cram [tʃga] into a single note, then it's likely not.  Do you have any clips?

Comment: @guifa I think I was seeing syllabic consonants where there aren't. I replaced "d'bɔʃ" (which actually has something between the d and b) and updated the other transcriptions.

Comment: I'll keep looking for musical evidence, but I really doubt there would be sung syllabic consonants. (Aside from maybe in fast speech, I'm not sure if this dialect has any syllabic consonants.) If one wanted to put 2 syllables on one of those words, one would probably choose a different pronunciation from another dialect.

Comment: @DanGetz Have you any idea how the word "school" is in that language? Does it begin with `sk` or `isk`?

Comment: "There are other cases of prothetic vowels in this dialect though." such as?

Comment: Also, (I'm just curious) what do [tʃga], [pʰta], [fka], and [zbi] actually mean?

Comment: @KennyLau from Portuguese *chegar* (arrive), *botar* (throw), *ficar* (stay), and *subir* (rise).

Comment: Still waiting for other prothetic examples xd

Comment: Maybe that language has a completely different rule of where to add a prothetic vowel. It would help if you could provide more examples.

Comment: From the (highly limited) data that I have, the only rule I could inference is this: `cvCV` -> `acCV`, `CVcv` -> `CVcv`.

Comment: Basically, it means that the stress is what determines whether a word has prothetic vowel.

Comment: @KennyLau so are you looking for examples *without* prothetic vowels, too? Did you take the words that formed new initial consonant clusters into consideration? (`cvCV` → `ccV`)

Comment: Oh, I ignored them. So my hypothesis is disproven.

Comment: I also thought of voiced vs unvoiced, but this hypothesis is disproven by [zbi]. The point remains: I need more data.

Comment: @KennyLau I understand, but I don't think the question body or comments would be the place to dump a large list of words, unless you can direct me to what kinds of words I should find. (Also I should mention if it wasn't clear that I'm not a linguist or student, just an enthusiast, so there's a lot I don't know or might confuse.) There are IPA transcriptions of a number of words in the Wikipedia article, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Verdean_Creole#Dialects) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Verdean_Creole#Example_2_.28S.C3.A3o_Vicente_variant.29).

Comment: I'm also just an enthusiast :)

Comment: [ʒdam] for ajudar-me?

Comment: @KennyLau yes, but that's weird, the Wikipedia article doesn't seem to know of the phenomenon this question is about at all. They also have "mdjor" instead of "amdjor". I originally thought there was no vowel but was corrected by a native speaker to add the "a". Maybe this is sub-dialectal?

Comment: I can't find a prothetic vowel in your two links?

Comment: @KennyLau yeah, that's the thing. These prothetic vowels are apparently not consistent across all the speakers of this dialect, if that article doesn't mention them. But you can see "amdjer" in [these song lyrics](http://genius.com/Cesaria-evora-amdjer-de-nos-terra-lyrics). Haven't found a source for [iʒ'da] yet.

Comment: I'll continue this tomorrow.

Comment: Considering that you have listed a bunch of consonant clusters *without* prothetic, and only 4 *with* prothetic, could you please provide more examples of the prothetic vowels?

Comment: @KennyLau those are the 4 words that I know of with a vowel added to the beginning, compared to the Portuguese root.

Comment: @DanGetz I really can't say anything if I only have 4 examples. The most I could say is that [ʒ] and [m] initials undergo prothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Without historical data on the dialect, I'd think that the second hypothesis (Or might this be best explained as dropping the [u] by syncope and adding a [i] by prothesis?) sounds natural and plausible.

But maybe, you can dig up historical records shedding more light on the evolution of the São Vicente dialect of Cape Verdean Creole.

Comment: Just looking at those few examples, how about initial syllable metathesis followed by fronting of the vowel via unstressed /u/ -> [ʉ] -> [i]? In the absence of more data (especially, historical data) it's all just guesswork.